# Images too large when wrapped with with css generated content

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have a [sample page here](http://designbymgc.com/test/)

As you can see, the "recipe maker" and "video" images in that 4-up row overflow their parents.

The are in a standard Zurb Foundation 3 "block-grid" and, as such, are set to max-width 100%.  All the images WITHOUT the orange bar on top work fine.

Also, this whole setup works fine in Webkit browsers (Chrome 26, Safari 6, iOS): it does not work in FF (21) or IE (10).

If I remove display inline block from the callout, the image size goes back to normal, but I need the orange boxed text to be at the top, as in Webkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding max-width to the callout fixes it. Without that the images are becoming too wide:

```
.callout { 
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

This also fixes it in Opera, as it originally only works in WebKit browsers.